# iniciar una función en Ionic de manera constante

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript

actualmente estoy aprendiendo desarrollo de aplicaciones con ionic
tengo el siguiente problema. tengo una aplicacion de la plantilla "sidemenu" la que viene con el menú lateral, ese menu se genera por un arreglo que existe en  app.component.ts una opcion de ese menu me lleva a una pagina que tiene la siguiente implementacion

```
export class FavoritesPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myfunction();
  }
  myfunction(){
    console.log('HolaMundo');
  }
}
```

cuando entro a la pagina se carga ngOnInit() y este ejecuta myfunction() que me imprime un mensaje en consola, hasta ahí genial, pero si retrocedo al home y luego vuelvo a entrar, ya no se vuelve a ejecutar, hay manera de que siempre se ejecute cuando entre a esta pagina? he probado poniéndolo también en el constructor pero solo se ejecuta una vez? que necesitaría para que siempre se ejecute? gracias.

Comment: Ya somos dos, no soy de ayuda ya que no tengo ese conocimiento, requiero algo así también, por lo que sería muy útil la respuesta a esta pregunta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

existen diferentes ciclos de vida de las vistas de ionic, en tu caso para ejecutar un código cada vez que se entra en una vista deberías usar **ionViewDidEnter**.

```
export class FavoritesPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myfunction();
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.myfunction();
  }

  myfunction(){
    console.log('HolaMundo');
  }
}
```

Mas info:

**ionViewDidLoad**: Este evento se lanza cuando la página ha terminado de cargar, hemos de tener en cuenta que si la página es cacheada no se lanzará la segunda vez ni posteriores.

**ionViewWillEnter**: Se ejecuta cuando entras en una página, pero antes de ser cargada. De este modo podemos realizar acciones como llamar a una base de datos para actualizar los datos de la vista y posteriormente pintarlos en la propia vista.

**ionViewDidEnter**: Se ejecuta cuando entras en una página, pero siempre después de que haya sido cargada y esté como página activa.

**ionViewWillLeave**: Se llama justo antes de dejar una página. Podemos utilizar este evento para desactivar listeners, etc.

**ionViewDidLeave**: Este evento se lanza justo cuando la página en la que estábamos ya no está activa.

**ionViewWillUnload**: Se ejecuta cuando la página y todos sus eventos están a punto de ser destruidos (pop).

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono como quería